# django REST framework - limited queryset for nested ModelSerializer?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a `ModelSerializer`, but by default it serializes all the objects in my model.  I would like to limit this queryset to only the most recent 500 (as opposed to all 50 million). How do I do this?

What I have currently is the following:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

The reason I don't think I can just specify the queryset in my viewset is that this is in fact the nested portion of another serializer.

### models.py

```
class Container(models.Model):
    size  = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    shape = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Item(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container, related_name='items')
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

### views.py

```
class ContainerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Container.objects.all()  # only a handful of containers
    serializer_class = ContainerSerializer
```

### serializers.py

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('name', 'color')

class ContainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True)  # millions of items per container
    class Meta:
        model = Container
        fields = ('size', 'shape', 'items')
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In your View Set you may specify the queryset like follows:

```
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()[:500]
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

I think what you are looking for is the [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

So your code would look as follows:

```
class ContainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = SerializerMethodField('get_items')

    class Meta:
        model = Container
        fields = ('size', 'shape', 'items')

    def get_items(self, container):
        items = Item.objects.filter(container=container)[:500]  # Whatever your query may be
        serializer = ItemSerializer(instance=items, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

The one catch is that the `SerializerMethodField` is read only.

Comment: Thanks -- I've edited my question to explain my situation more thoroughly.

Comment: Updated answer per your updated question. Let me know if it works

Comment: Just a detail. You don´t need to specify 'get_items' on SerializerMethodField(...) as it is inferred automatically using always "get_" + property name

Comment: @xleon thanks its good to know that. But unless we are very familiar, we may still prefer being explicit..

Comment: @Yeo as of the latest Django Rest Framework release, specifying 'get_'+property name in the SerializerMethodField(...) on the ModelSerializer class will throw an AssertionError because it's considered redundant. So, if you're using ModelSerializer, do not pass the function name to SerializerMethodField(...).

Comment: If the `ItemSerializer` contains fields that require the context, such as a `HyperlinkedIdentityField`, you can pass `context=self.context` as a third argument to the `ItemSerializer` instantiation.

Comment: I've just recently started to use DRF at work and, actually, `SerializerMethodField` looks like a silver bullet. Yay.

Comment: Our usecase was that the nested relationship queryset was determined by the state of the user, in a pseudo-multitenant situation. We used this technique to filter the nested relationship to only those records that should be returned for the user.

Answer (score 21):

You may use *source* parameter

```
class Container(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_items(self):
        return self.items[:500]
```

and in serializer

```
items = ItemSerializer(many=True, source='get_items', )
```

Comment: I think this answer is more explicit than @Johndt6's, which method is kinda like a view. This one more serializer style, returning objects as many=true.

Comment: I don't believe this would work if you need to access  the context of the request at the time of generation. For example, if you allow the user to set the page size in the request parameters then this model method would not be able to access that param. Unless I'm mistaken...