# Django Rest framework: Limit number of fields while using serialzer as nested object

Tags: django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

A serializer in my code is used at two different places.

First Use : Direct

```
    class FirstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta(object):
            model = FirstSerializer
            fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'line1', 'line2',)
```

Second Use : Within another serializer

```
    class SecondSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        first_serilizer = FirstSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta(object):
        model = SecondSerializer
```

- In first usecase, I need all fields.
- In second usecase, while using it as nested object I want to exclude 'line2' from the list of fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django REST framework - limited queryset for nested ModelSerializer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312987/django-rest-framework-limited-queryset-for-nested-modelserializer)

Comment: You have to specify the fields on 'FirstSerializer' to limit the fields, by default DRF modelserializer will serialize the complete model. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

Comment: @GwynBleidD that question is about limiting querryset not fields.

Comment: @PieterHamman Actually I have added fields which I am using in viewset but here for nested object I want to use limited fields. I have updated question, Can you please take a look ?

Comment: @TasawerNawaz, I would just subclass the FirstSerializer as I said in my answer, if you are looking for a more generic way of doing this you can have a look at this DynamicSerializer in the docs http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will subclass the 'FirstSerializer' class to limit code duplication and specify only the needed fields on the 'PartialFirstSerializer',

```
class FirstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
        model = FirstModel

class PartialFirstSerializer(FirstSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'line1')

class SecondSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_serializer = PartialFirstSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SecondModel
```

If you are looking for a more generic solution the DRF docs shows you how to create a DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, that takes a fields attribute. 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
           # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
           allowed = set(fields)
           existing = set(self.fields.keys())
           for field_name in existing - allowed:
               self.fields.pop(field_name)

class FirstSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
        model = FirstModel

class SecondSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_serializer = FirstSerializer(fields=('first_name', 'last_name', 'line1'), many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SecondModel
```

Comment: What are the benefits of second approach? According to my understanding subclassing it makes more sense to readability and keeps things simple.

Comment: @iankit the second approach is just more dynamic and DRY, if you would do the same thing on multiple occasions. If this is a one time thing I would just subclass the 'FirstSerializer'