# Merging django-rest-framework results

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm making my first API and it's almost what I want.  I'm trying to be able to give users access both individually, and through their groups, but I would like to setup the API to show all of the access the user has plainly instead of having it embedded in the group.

Basically, I want to take the group_affiliation results and merge them into the rest of the results since they are of the same structure, and would be easier to use in that format.

Currently, my output looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "username": "admin",
        "access": [
            {
                "name": "foo"
            },
            {
                "name": "bar"
            }
        ],
        "group_affiliation": [
            {
                "access": [
                    {
                        "name": "eggs"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "foo"
                    }
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

But I would like it to look more like this, where the group_affiliation results are merged into the other results:

```
[
    {
        "username": "admin",
        "access": [
            {
                "name": "foo"
            },
            {
                "name": "bar"
            },
            {
                "name": "eggs"
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

Here is my models.py:

```
class Access(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    site_user_access = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    site_group_access = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True)
```

And here is my serializers.py:

```
class AccessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TopAccess
        fields = ('name', )


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    access = AccessSerializer(
            source='access_set',
            many=True
            )

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = (
                'access',
                )


class UserAccessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    access = AccessSerializer(
            source='access_set',
            many=True
            )
    group_affiliation = GroupSerializer(
            source='groups',
            many=True,
            )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
                'username',
                'access',
                'group_affiliation',
                )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? You need to be more specific, and only include the minimum amount of code needed to explain your problem. [mcve]

Comment: @HåkenLid I'm trying to merge the results that show up under "group_affiliation" into the rest of the results. I edited the code so that it's a bit more concise

Comment: use a serializer method field to make your custom output

Comment: override serializer's to_representation(), return your custom object from this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @zaphod100.10 and the people of Betelgeuse V for pointing me in the correct direction as well as this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312987/django-rest-framework-limited-queryset-for-nested-modelserializer) for giving me the syntax.

Here is my solution:

```
class AccessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Access
        fields = ('name', )


class UserAccessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    access = SerializerMethodField('access_set')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
                'username',
                'access',
                )

    def access_set(self, user):
        queryset = Access.objects.filter(site_user_access=user)
        queryset = queryset | Access.objects.filter(site_group_access__user=user)
        queryset = queryset.distinct()
        serializer = AccessSerializer(instance=queryset, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Which give the desired result listed above