# Django custom queryset inside ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have a `PostSerializer` that has a `comments` field which use `CommentSerializer`. I want to change the queryset of this `CommentSerializer` so that it won't show all comments at once. Here's the code

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = SimplifiedCommentSerializer(
        many=True,
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('comments')

class SimplifiedCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.TextField()

    # this function doesn't seem to work
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Comment.objects.all()[:10]

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('content')
```

I've tried using get_queryset inside the `SimplifiedCommentSerializer`, but I still get all the comments instead of the first 10.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get all comments instead of the first then?

Comment: yeah, I still get all the comments instead of the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Comment.objects.all()[:10]
```

into:

```
queryset = Comment.objects.all()[:10]
```

EDIT:

Create a viewset and outsource the line above:

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()[:10]
    serializer_class = SimplifiedCommentSerializer
```

Please see this question and answer:
[django REST framework - limited queryset for nested ModelSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312987/django-rest-framework-limited-queryset-for-nested-modelserializer/25313145)

Comment: I still get all the comments with this