# How to show only a few Many-to-many relations in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

If for an example I have 2 models and a simple View:

```py
class Recipe(model.Model):
    created_at = model.DateField(auto_add_now=True)


class RecipeBook(model.Model):
    recipes = model.ManyToManyField(Recipe)

...

class RecipeBookList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = RecipeBook.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeBookSerializer

...

class RecipeBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recipe = RecipeSerializer(many=True, read_ony=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = RecipeBook
        fields = "__all__"
```

What would be the best way, when showing all Restaurants with a simple `GET` method,  to show only the first 5 recipes created and not all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuerySet way:

You can specify custom `Prefetch` operation in your queryset to limit the prefetched related objects:

```
queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('recipes', queryset=Recipe.objects.all()[:5]))
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects

Serializer way:

You can use `source` to provide a custom method to return a custom queryset

```
class RecipeBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recipes = RecipeSerializer(many=True, read_only=Treue, source='get_recipes')

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeBook
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_recipes(self, obj):
        return obj.recipes.all()[:5]
```

Then use `prefetch_related("recipes")` to minimize related queries.

Source: [django REST framework - limited queryset for nested ModelSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312987/django-rest-framework-limited-queryset-for-nested-modelserializer)

The problem with the serializer way is that either a related query for recipes is performed per recipe book object or all related recipes are pre-fetched from the beginning.

Comment: There is an N+1 issue with this approach, since you'll make additional DB query for the recipes per each RecipeBook you show

Comment: Oh yea that's true, thanks @Alexandr, ant idea for a more optimal solution?

Comment: Nice one, did not notice that issue. Edited with improved query

Comment: wouldn't `prefetch_related` pull all of them when doing the query? (and i want to avoid that) Any way to avoid doing that and specify to fetch the 5 most recent ones?

Comment: okay i think i found a solution to limit the number of pre_fetched elements with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37086807/7269139 Thanks for the help Dan/Alex

Comment: Nikola, I was just in the progress of editing with a similar solution as the one you commented here :) Good job!